# CSRF failure on server using Remote Authentication (works when cookie is cleared)

Tags: django, cookies, nginx, csrf, django-csrf

I'm using Django's `RemoteUserMiddleware` to authenticate the users in one website. It works great until the next day. When I try to do anything using POST methods (even in Django's admin page) it gives me a 403 error.

I clear the cookies and it starts to work again.

There's a firewall in between my browser and the server which sends the headers to the server (so Django can know who is logged in).

Django's version: 1.9.6
I'm using NGINX in my server

When the error occurs django changes the csrftoken each time. It seems it is getting an Anonymous User when the cache is not cleared...

Any thoughts what could be causing this weird behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due one invalid cookie being injected by the system. Django doesn't handle well whenever there is an invalid cookie... it kind wipes some of the keys in the meta tag (where the cookies are checked)